# Print awk output on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, printing, xrandr

How do I print awk output on the same line.

I am using this to print the resolution of my monitor:

```
$ xrandr | awk '/\*/{print $1}'
```

When I connect a second monitor I get output on two lines,

```
$ xrandr | awk '/\*/{print $1}'

1920x1200
1600x1050
```

I would like to have the output on the same line. So it will look like this:

```
Monitor sizes: 1920x1200 1600x1050
```

How would I do this the simplest way?

Comment: `xrandr | awk '/\*/{printf "%s ", $1}'; echo`

Comment: Oh my, I like this very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution that is similar to what anubhava posted.

```
    $ xrandr | awk '/\*/{printf $1" "}'
    1920x1200 1600x1050
```

Comment: @anubhava added an `echo` for a newline after both sizes. Another way is adding the `awk` statement `END {print}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can append `xargs` to your command, e.g.

```
$ xrandr | awk '/\*/{print $1}' | xargs
```

Here is alternative command using `grep` and `xargs`:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9]\+x[0-9]\+' <(xrandr) | xargs
1440x878 2880x1800 1440x900 2560x1600 2048x1280 1024x768 800x600 640x480 1680x1050 1280x800 1440x878
```

Or using `echo`:

```
$ echo Monitor sizes: $(grep -o '[0-9]\+x[0-9]\+' <(xrandr))
Monitor sizes: 1440x878 2880x1800
```

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to know `paste`:

```
xrandr | awk '/\*/{print $1}' | paste - -
```

You can also iuse `echo`:

```
echo $(xrandr | awk '/\*/ {print $1}' )
```